# Get the calling object of a block

Tags: ruby, block

If I have a class `Object1` with a method `method1` and a "global" `method2` inside the `Kernel` module.

`method1` run the block by transforming it into a proc and then call it.

If I have something like that :

```
obj1 = new Object1
obj1.method1(arg1,arg2){ method2() }
```

Is it possible in `method2` to know that `obj1` called the block ?

Comment: `method2` does not need to be in the `Kernel` module but need to be accessed in every blocks passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want method2 to be a global method. You get get the the access to the calling object by passing a binding. But a much more simpler way is just to pass the caller object to it:

**Example:**

```
def method2(o)
  #puts this.object_id
  puts "Inside method2()"
  puts "#{o.object_id}"
end


class Object1
  def method1
    method2(self)
  end
end

obj1 = Object1.new

puts obj1.object_id

obj1.method1()
```

**Output:**

```
23644040
Inside method2()
23644040
```